# Can't get puppet to enable apache mods

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet

I want to use puppet to install apache and enable some modules so I installed the *puppetlabs/apache* module and tried to use it.

Apache installs fine but the modules aren't enabled at all. I tried it like it is described in the readme

```
class { 'apache': }
class { 'apache::mod::ssl': }
class { 'apache::mod::fcgid': }
class { 'apache::mod::suexec': }
```

and also like this

```
include apache
a2mod { "Enable ssl":
    name => "ssl",
    ensure => "present"
}
...
```

Neither are the modules installed (*libapache2-mod-fcgid*, *apache2-suexec*) nor are they enabled.

Server is Ubuntu 12.04

UPDATE: `--debug` output

```
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Suexec/Apache::Mod[suexec]/Package[apache2-suexec]/require: requires Package[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Suexec/Apache::Mod[suexec]/Package[apache2-suexec]/before: requires A2mod[suexec]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Fcgid/Apache::Mod[fcgid]/A2mod[fcgid]/require: requires Package[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Fcgid/Apache::Mod[fcgid]/A2mod[fcgid]/notify: subscribes to Service[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Suexec/Apache::Mod[suexec]/A2mod[suexec]/require: requires Package[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Suexec/Apache::Mod[suexec]/A2mod[suexec]/notify: subscribes to Service[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Ssl/Apache::Mod[ssl]/A2mod[ssl]/require: requires Package[httpd]
/Stage[main]/Apache::Mod::Ssl/Apache::Mod[ssl]/A2mod[ssl]/notify: subscribes to Service[httpd]
```

UPDATE: required packages for *fcgid* and *suexec* are installed now and the *fcgid* mod is even enabled, but *suexec* and *ssl* mods stay disabled.

Comment: Do you have the dependencies setup so that Apache is completely installed before you try to enable the module?  Are you getting any errors?  If you run the puppet agent with the `--debug` option, what you see related to the a2mod?

Comment: added debug output into the main question. there are no errors or other A2mod related outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and finally gave the example42/apache module a try instead.  Works like a charm.

In my case:

```
class { "apache": }

apache::module { 'ldap':
        install_package => false,
}
```

Comment: yeah, did it for me too...